Table in Confluence with Jira issue filter that changes the content and added comments in Confluence
I'm trying to figure out if there is even an possibility to do this in Confluence. And if so, how?
I have a list of Epics with a certain fixversion that I want to show in a table on a Confluence page. I would then like to add some extra columns in this Confluence table to add comments/checkboxes etc.



Issuenumber (from Jira filter)
Epic name (from Jira filter)
Fix version (from Jira filter)
Comments in Confluence




12345
New functionality 1
4
Test work done


12347
New functionality 2
4
Refinement ongoing



How do I create something like this in case something changes in the fix version, meaning the content of the table changes? Is it possible to have the content in the last column to line up with the correct issue?



Issuenumber
Epic name
Fix version (from Jira filter)
Comments in Confluence




12345
New functionality 1
4
Test work done


12346
New functionality 3
4



12347
New functionality 2
4
Refinement ongoing



I have not found a macro that could do this.
